# React components are rendered twice, function components that don't use state hooks are rendered only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Demo code's codesandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-goldstine-gmvz4

Class component is rendered twice, without Props and State; Function components that do not use `useState` hook are rendered only once and using `useState` hook will render twice.

Is it rendered twice for get State and Props values?

A class component is a stateful component whether or not the state is initialized?

Can anyone help me understand this question? Thank you!!!

additional a image:
[image]

Comment: in your example, i can see CR twice and FR... twice. So, what is your question again ?

Comment: What does class components twice render do?

Comment: It is happening because of `React.StrictMode` you are using in your code. If you remove that, It's working fin.

Comment: I removed `React.StrictMode`, but it didn't change, it still rendered twice

Comment: FP component is rendered twice because of using `useState` hook，But I don't understand why the CR component is rendered twice

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can better help you.

Comment: You have `React.StrictMode` twice, one in your `index.js` and one in your `App.js`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my careless, i neglect `index.js` file, thank you for answering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment @Sagar More, `StricktMode` cause it.

Output without `StrickMode`
[image]

See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following methods:
>
> Class component constructor method
>
> The **render** method
>
> setState updater functions (the first argument)
>
> The static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle
>
> The shouldComponentUpdate method

Comment: For people like me, go to the "index.js" and remove "<React.StrictMode>" tag